# Elasticsearch JAVA API for script tag

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have to query elasticsearch for sum of two fields in a doc, that fall in a particular range.

I'm trying to create a Java API for the below elastic search query, but not able to make out how to include script tags and select doc elements i.e doc['maintenanceCost']. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
   "query": {
       "bool" : {
           "filter" : {
               "script" : {
                   "script" : "doc['price'].value + doc['maintenanceCost'].value  > 1000 && doc['price'].value + doc['maintenanceCost'].value  < 10000"     
           }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I basically need docs in which sum of price and`enter code here` maintenance cost fall between 1000 to 10000

I have tried out few queries like ScriptBuilders, but none of them worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use QueryBuilders.scriptQuery() with the Script object for this. In your case it would be something like this:

```
QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(
        new Script("doc['price'].value + doc['maintenanceCost'].value  > 1000 && doc['price'].value + doc['maintenanceCost'].value  < 10000")                  
    );
```

More detailed information about this method can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-specialized-queries.html#java-query-dsl-script-query).